# h:message show Messages in different positions

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces, jsf-2.2

i have a problem in `h:message`, it shows the `requiredMessage` in a different position of the `validatorMessage`, and i want it to show them in the same position!!
here is my code :

```
<h:form>
    <h:panelGrid columns="3" width="800" border="0">
        <p:outputLabel value="login *" />
        <p:inputText id="login" value="#{acteurAuth.login}" label="Login"
                     required="true" requiredMessage="Login est obligatoire"
                     validatorMessage="5-->6">
            <f:ajax event="blur"  render="loginMsg" />
            <f:validateLength minimum="5" maximum="6"/>
        </p:inputText>
        <h:message id="loginMsg" for="login"/>`

        <p:outputLabel value="mot de passe  *" />
        <p:password id="pwd" value="#{acteurAuth.password}" label="mot de passe"
                    required="true" requiredMessage="Mot de passe est obligatoire" >
            <f:ajax event="blur"  render="pwdMsg" />
        </p:password>
        <h:message id="pwdMsg" for="pwd"/>          

        <p:commandButton value="Valider"
                         action="#{acteurAuth.authentification()}" />
    </h:panelGrid>
</h:form>
```

Comment: have a look here http://www.mkyong.com/jsf2/jsf-2-message-and-messages-example/

Comment: Remove width attribute and check if the problem still occurs.